# Remove items with matching key from array

Tags: javascript, knockout.js

I have a knockout view model which contains an array of Row objects and an array of VisibleColumns objects as shown in the following screen grab:

[image]

As you can see, the VisibleCoumns array contains values which match the keys of the Rows array.

I would like to remove key value pairs of the Rows array where the key **cannot** be found in the VisibleColumns array.

These array are going to be quite large so I'm wondering if there's a typical javascript way of doing this kind of thing that is quite efficient?

Comment: Do you use underscorejs?

Comment: 'fraid not. I am quite new to the JS world - just starting to use KnockoutJs

Comment: have you tried using `ko.utils` filters to filter the array as per your need

Comment: @RobBowman if you can make up some dummy data to showcase your array structure i can help you with filtering .cheers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this:

```
for (var i = 0; i < Rows.length; i++) {
    var row = Rows[i];

    var keys = Object.keys(row);
    for (var k = 0; k < keys.length; k++) {
        if (VisibleColumns.indexOf(keys[k]) === (-1)) {
            delete row[keys[k]];
        }
    }
}
```